# Making an AJAX callback for every row in a table / MVC 4 ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-ajax

I'm creating a View which will ping a list of servers and display status once a response is received:

- Server 1 - * Waiting for response *
- Server 2 - * Response received *
- Server 3 - * Waiting for response *

On page load they will all (theoretically) display * Waiting for response *, but as each response is received the table will be updated. A response can take anywhere between 0 and, say, 30 seconds.

I need an ajax callback for each row.

I'm a windows developer so struggle with best practices when it comes to web/ajax. What would be the right way to approach this?

Comment: Whoever downvoted this question immediately - I'd appreciate a reason. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think jquery ajax function is enough. To update website you can use Knockout/AngularJS.

You can create KO obeservable array of strings and do something like this:

```
 rows = ko.observableArray();

// this in onload

//fill rows with { ServerName, Status = "Waiting for response"}

 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "yoururl/function/row" //row is row number
        }).done(function(){ rows()[row].Status = "Response received"; });
```

and html:

```
<table>
<!-- header here -->
<tbody data-bind="foreach: rows">
                    <tr>
                        <td data-bind="text: ServerName"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: Status"></td>
                    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```